# Access the Username and Password Entered in the Browser Login Popup From jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

When I access a site requiring authentication, the browser shows the login popup.  How can I access the username and password entered there from jQuery?  I'm not talking about fields in a web page form, but the popup generated by the browser.

Comment: Do you have access to the window.open method?

Comment: You mean basic-authentication & the browsers built-in dialog? If so you can't, you need to write it back to the page from the server (usually its in the server variables collection)

Comment: Why would you need to access this in the client? Once you've authenticated to the server, isn't that good enough?

Comment: Currently, the credentials authorization string is hard-coded in the javascript.  I need to get that out of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this directly. As a work around you can create a page on the website that allows anonymous authentication so the dialog isn't triggered and then use jQuery on that page to collect a username and password and perform the authentication for you.

As described here [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax):

jQuery (1.7.2+)

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

Or, pre 1.7.2 use headers instead of username and password

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: The second option is what we're currently doing, but we can't hard code the credentials in the page.